# ical4j Illegal Property on ical new line

Tags: android, parsing, ical4j

I have an issue parsing an ical file using ical4j. The location tag is formatted as follows:

```
UID:1
LOCATION: 
Kingston Park
SEQUENCE:0
```

Because 'Kingston Park' is on a new line, I get the following parsing exception:

Illegal Property: Kingston Park

I have set relaxed unfolding to true. Is there any way I can ignore this new line?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only way this will work is if there is at least one space preceding 'Kingston Park' at the start of the line.

The reason is that folded lines are identified by a space at the beginning of the line, and every line without a space at the beginning is regarded as a new content line.

The relaxed unfolding property is really just to allow for non-standard line terminators (i.e. '\n' rather than '\r\n'), and tabs at the beginning of folded lines rather than a space.

Comment: OK thanks. I guess this is properly formatted iCal though as it works fine in calendars. Therefore this is a ical4j bug?

Comment: I don't think this is a bug, and I don't see how this would work with any other parser due to how line folding works (as explained above). Try using an online ical validator (serveringhaus or icalvalid) to verify if the file is valid.